# ParseQuery include returning null

Tags: java, android, null, parse-platform

For an app I'm working on, I'm using Parse ([www.parse.com](http://parse.com)) and I have two different pointer arrays in the _User class. That class contains two columns that I'm trying to include in my query: "following" and "friends".

My problem is that the result is always either null or empty pointers, depending on how I query it.

Parse mentions:

> In some situations, you want to return multiple types of related objects in one query. You can do this with the include method.

However, using this `include` method causes the results to be null. This is my code:

```
ParseQuery<AAUser> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(AAUser.class);
query.include("following");
query.include("friends");
query.getInBackground(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId, new GetCallback<AAUser>() {
    @Override
    public void done(AAUser user, ParseException e) {
        if(e != null)
            return;

        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(user.getFollowing()));
    }
});
```

`user.getFollowing()` alwas returns `[null]` whenever I include that field. However, if I don't include it, it returns an empty pointer as it should. `[AALocation{id='iLUigvrvrc'}]`

As you can see, I queried my subclassed AAUser class. I still get the same results by querying the ParseUser class so I don't see how subclassing made a difference.

How can I solve this issue? Is this a bug with the Parse SDK? I'm using version 1.7.1 of the Parse Android SDK.

.

I'm basically trying to refresh the current user data with these fields included but I see it's not working as it should...
 And yes, I tried fetchInBackground() but it doesn't give me any ways to include those fields. My current workaround is to use the empty pointers and query all of them one by one but I find this to be an awful workaround... please halp.

Comment: have you checked document of this link?
https://parse.com/docs/android_guide

Comment: @dipali Yes I have. That's what I quoted in my question. According to that document, my current code should work yet it doesn't...

Comment: what you exactly want? plz describe

Comment: @dipali I want to execute this query and include the two arrays but Parse is returning null for some reason instead of the arrays.

Comment: please check what value for "query"?is it null?

Comment: @dipali The query itself is fine. The only thing null is the array returned from the query in user.getFollowing(). It returns a List full of null values.

Comment: What is common field of all 3 table?

Comment: I don't think you can "include" an array. You'll have to do a seperate PFObject.fetchAllInBackground

Comment: can you show us your AAUser class implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("_User");
         query.include("following");
         query.include("friends");
         query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() 
          {
              public void done(List<ParseObject> followinglist, ParseException e) 
              {

                for (ParseObject following : followinglist) 
                {
                  ParseObject follow = following.getParseObject("following");
                  ParseObject friend=following.getParseObject("friends");


                }
              }
            });
```

Comment: This isn't really working, unfortunately. :/
"following" and "friends" are both supposed to return an ArrayList containing ParseObjects. For some reason, even your code also returned null.

Comment: @Pkmmte: Try this                                             for(ParseObject following : followinglist) 
{
    String follow = following.getString("following");                 
}